# How do I show pie chart in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

I'm trying to show a chart in Asp.Net MVC but it always open in another window. I want to show it without opened another window, in the same window.

How could I do it ?

**_GraficoPerformance**

```
@model ResumoMovtoTrades

<div class="text-center">
    <p>
        @{ 
            var macChart = new Chart(200,200)
               .AddTitle("Performance")
               .AddSeries(
                name: "Performance",
                chartType: "Pie",
                legend: "Performance",
                xValue: new[] { "Gain", "Loss" },
                yValues: new[] { Model.qtdGain, Model.qtdLoss })
            .Write();
        }
    </p>
</div>
```

**Show _PartialView**

```
<div class="panel panel-blue">
            <div class="panel-heading bg-blue">Gráfico de Performance</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               <img src="@Html.Partial("_GraficoPerformance", @Model.resumoMovtos)"/>
            </div>
        </div><!--/panelchart-->
```

Comment: It makes no sense to have a HTML document as the "src" of an image. The "src" should be either a URL to an image file (or a script that returns image data), or a base64 string. Have a look at your View Source after this is rendered in the browser...I think you'll see HTML tags inside the src property, which isn't going to work.

Comment: try changing `<img src="@Html.Partial("_GraficoPerformance", @Model.resumoMovtos)"/>` to just `@Html.Partial("_GraficoPerformance", @Model.resumoMovtos)`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a jquery library to show the graphic and it works well.

I used this: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/